# Why I got error Type 'mamlaka_lab.BL.SendClass' cannot be serialized?

Tags: c#

I need to make SMS program using C# ,
I took the sample code from the SMS company and paste it to my project
But its not sending when click SEND button and got this error :

```
 Type 'mamlaka_lab.BL.SendClass' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
```

This is the complete code :

1- SendClass :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace mamlaka_lab.BL
{
    class SendClass
    {
        private string _recipients = string.Empty;
        private string _body = string.Empty;
        private string _sender = string.Empty;

        [DataMember()]
        public string recipients
        {
            set
            {
                _recipients = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _recipients;
            }
        }

        [DataMember()]
        public string body
        {
            set
            {
                _body = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _body;
            }
        }

        [DataMember()]
        public string sender
        {
            set
            {
                _sender = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _sender;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2- JsonSerialize Code:

```
private string JSONSerialize(mamlaka_lab.BL.SendClass objStudent)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(mamlaka_lab.BL.SendClass));
            jsonSer.WriteObject(stream, objStudent);
            stream.Position = 0;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

3- SMSSEND_Click Code:

```
private void SMSSEND_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            string strResponse;
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.taqnyat.sa/v1/messages");
                req.Method = "POST";

                req.ContentType = "application/json";
                req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + TxtBearer.Text);
                
                mamlaka_lab.BL.SendClass objStudent = new mamlaka_lab.BL.SendClass();

                //  objStudent.body = smsBody;
                //  objStudent.recipients = txtMobile.Text;
                //  objStudent.sender = sender.ToString();

                objStudent.body = TxtBody.Text;
                objStudent.recipients = TxtRecipients.Text;
                objStudent.sender = TxtSender.Text;


                Byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JSONSerialize(objStudent));
                req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                Stream newStream = req.GetRequestStream();
                newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                newStream.Close();


                StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                strResponse = stIn.ReadToEnd();
                stIn.Close();


                TxtResult.Text = strResponse;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse1 = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    try
                    {
                        using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                            {
                                strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }

                       TxtBalance.Text = strResponse;
                    }
                    catch (Exception exGetResp)
                    {
                        throw exGetResp;
                    }

                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
            }

        }
```

when I run the application sample code given from the SMS provider its sending the message
but when I copy the code into my project its not sending and show this error ,

I checked the whole code line by line but its not sending from my project ,

I need your help please how to solve this error

when I run the application I write bearer code , sender , receiver and SMS text then click send button

In this link sample code from SMS provider

[enter link description here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/gw2cnfzih5zla0l/C#_SAMPLE_CODE.zip/file)

Comment: The [DataContract] attribute is missing, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you so much adding [DataContract] to SendClass solved the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try adding the [DataContract] to your SendClass.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=net-6.0#examples

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To be fair, @Community: I suspect that the answer is correct, though (given the choice of serializer)

Comment: Thank you so much adding [DataContract] to SendClass solved the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much my friends adding the [DataContract] to SendClass solved the issue and SMS was sent.

This is the final SendClass :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace mamlaka_lab.BL
{
    [DataContract]

    class SendClass
    {
        private string _recipients = string.Empty;
        private string _body = string.Empty;
        private string _sender = string.Empty;
               
        [DataMember()]
        public string recipients
        {
            set { _recipients = value; } 
            get { return _recipients;  }
        }

        [DataMember()]
        public string body
        {
            set { _body = value; }
            get {  return _body; }
        }

        [DataMember()]
        public string sender
        {
            set { _sender = value; }
            get { return _sender;  }
        }
    }
}
```